# How Can I Insert New Column Into A Database Table Using SqlDataAdapter and DataTable?

Tags: .net, ado.net, datatable, sqldataadapter

In my .NET program, I want to modify database table's structure by inserting new column. But I do NOT want to do it by running "ALTER TABLE ....." command on database by ADO.NET. I want to do it by adding new column to my datatable. So when I update the associated tableAdapter, physical table structure is going to change.

The code, which I expected to work was like this:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BirthDate"));
        adapter.Update(dt);
```

But it did not.

If it is possible in any way, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this.

The .NET datatable is only a representation of the on-disk database structures - there's no functionality in the ADO.NET DataTable code to support *generating* or *updating* the underlying tables when you change the structure of your DataTable.

You will have to use `ALTER TABLE .....` SQL statement to achieve what you're looking for - no way around that, I'm afraid.